# Price filter wrong value

Tags: jquery, slider

I have code like below

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0.6,
      max: 300,
      values: [ 0.6, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        alert('300');alert(ui.values[ 1 ]);
        $("#min_price").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        $("#max_price").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
      },
       stop: function( event, ui ) {
        get_filter_result();
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val("$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + 300);
  });
  </script>
```

the actual min value is 0.6 and max value is 117.. but when slider is created the range is shown from 0.6 to 116.6
I have noticed 1 thing it takes similar decimal value as in minimum..
means if min value is 15.8 then max value will be .8 after decimal..

Comment: Post your rendered code instead. If the PHP is working, we're not really interested in it, and if it isn't, the rendered code will contain useful clues to that.

Comment: I think problem is in his script.

Comment: This is likely, but we're not seeing the script, we're seeing the code that generates the script. Give us the resulting HTML & JavaScript.

Comment: <div class="sidebar_box">
              <h3><label for="amount">Price range:</label></h3>
              <div data-role="rangeslider" class="rangeslider">
                 <input type="text" id="amount" readonly >
                 <input type="hidden" id="min_price" value="<?php echo $min_max[0]['min_price']; ?>">
                 <input type="hidden" id="max_price" value="<?php echo $min_max[0]['max_price']; ?>">
                 <div id="slider-range"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

Comment: What I'm asking for is the actual code that is generated, not the PHP tags. When your page has loaded, right click and select "view source". Find your slider script in there, and provide us with that. And do it by updating your answer, don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using jQuery UI slider?

This slider accepts an option called `step` which sets the discrete intervals between `min` and `max`. The default value is `1`, meaning each step to the right in the slider increases the value by 1, which is probably what you are seeing.

If you want `0.6` to be a possible value, but also `1`, for instance, you will need to set `step` to a value that encompasses both those values, such as `0.1` or `0.2`.

```
min: 0.6,
max: 300,
step: 0.1,
```

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js this jquery i am using. can u pls help what i nedd to update in this for taking slider range values in floating point. like 0.1

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: You need to set the `step` property. I've updated my answer with a code example.

Comment: ok. this worked., but still some issue. i have taken step:0.01. i have min value 0.6 and maximum value of 300, but still it shows 0.6 to 299.99.. any solution for this ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that from the code you've posted. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bukxttg/)